# Need to get enum values as a drop down option in my View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am looking to set an employeetype as either Manager or Employee, I created a enum property but am unable to get the Manager and Employee values to populate in my create view.

My Model

```
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    public enum EmployeeType {Employee, Manager }
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
    public int AssignedStore { get; set; }
```

My View

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Use `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor`. It was only added in MVC 5, but since you're on MVC 5, you're good to go.

Comment: Just replace the @Html.LabelFor with @Html.EnumDropDownListFor?  Sorry, I'm very new to this as this is really only for a class I am in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference an enum as if it was a property on your model. Your model should be something like:

```
public class Foo
{
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public EmployeeType EmployeeType { get; set; }
   public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
   public int AssignedStore { get; set; }
}

public enum EmployeeType
{
    Employee,
    Manager
}
```

Notice that the enum is defined outside the class, and then the class has a property with your enum as the type. Now, you have a property that can actually hold a value, and this can be used in your view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```